# Validate phone number without regex in Java Spring MVC

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have form with text input element for phone number,

```
 <p>
        <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
        <form:input path="phone" id="phone" />

        <div style="text-align: center;">
        <form:errors path="phone" cssStyle="color : red;" /> 
        </div>
    </p>
```

For phone number, i have associated Phone domain class in actual domain class. I have used custom formatter for data binding the phone object.

```
@Valid
private Phone phone;
```

In my phone class, I have 3 phone number fields

```
private Integer area;

private Integer prefix;

private Integer number;
```

I want to validate area code and prefix of 3 digit, and number of 4 digit. How do i do this, without using any regex pattern?
Note: I have no problem in Data binding.

My phone formatter is like this:

```
@Component
public class PhoneFormatter implements Formatter<Phone> {

@Override
public String print(Phone phone, Locale arg1) {
    return String.valueOf(phone.getPrefix() + "-" + phone.getArea() + "-" + phone.getNumber());
}

@Override
public Phone parse(String phoneStr, Locale arg1) throws ParseException {
    int start = Integer.parseInt(phoneStr.substring(0, 2));
    int middle = Integer.parseInt(phoneStr.substring(3, 6));
    int end = Integer.parseInt(phoneStr.substring(7, 10));

    Phone phone = new Phone();
    phone.setPrefix(start);
    phone.setArea(middle);
    phone.setNumber(end);
    return phone;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to validate the `String phoneStr` in `parse()`, or validate the `Integer`s in `Phone`?

Comment: Why did you put a regex tag on the question while you specifically do not want a regex solution?

Comment: I want to validate a whole phone number when posting the form. As i have used @Valid annotation, that will look for every field validation on Phone model class. So, i want to validate the Integers in Phone.

Comment: Arjan , I have not put any regex in my code, these all used are JSR-303 anotations.

Comment: Yeah I noticed there's no regex in the code, there was a regex tag on the question though while it shouldn't be there.  Anyway, validating integers should not be too hard.  For example, you have a prefix of 3 digits.  So a valid prefix would always be in 0-999 range:  `boolean validPrefix = prefix > 0 && prefix <= 999`.  Of course you could narrow the range down if not all of those numbers are valid prefixes